# inserting an arbitrary element in map is ok, but not for vector

Tags: c++, stl

In the following example, inserting an element to an empty map without initializing its size is ok. But inserting an element in an empty vector will not work. What are the rules? Do all the sequential containers follow what vector does, and all the associated containers follow what map does, in this aspect? Why is it?

```
map<int, string> t;
t[1] = "string1";
for_each(t.begin(), t.end(), [](pair<int, string> x){cout << "(" << x.first << ", " << x.second << ") " << endl;});

vector<string> vt;
vt[0] = "string1";
for_each(vt.begin(), vt.end(), [](string x){cout << "(" << x << endl;});
```

Comment: Scott Meyers has gone into depth about the broader question here.  Standard container types are **not** interchangeable, even if they share the same required interface.

Comment: Can you show me a link of the broader question? I'd love to check it out. Thanks.

Comment: the book "Effective STL".

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
t[1] = "string1";
```

is fine because map's [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) will insert an element for that key if one isn't present.

This:

```
vt[0] = "string1";
```

is not fine because vector's [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) will just return that particular element - whether or not it's actually been constructed! If you want to just insert a new element, you want:

```
vt.push_back("string1");
vt.emplace_back("string1");
```

Or even:

```
vt.resize(1);
vt[0] = "string1";
```

> Do all the sequential containers follow what vector does, and all the associated containers follow what map does, in this aspect?

For the containers that support `operator[]`, I believe this is the general approach. Of course, not all of the sequential containers (e.g. `list`) or associative containers (e.g. `set`, `unordered_set`) do.

Comment: My guess is this is because you can insert stuff into a map willy-nilly, kind of what they are for, but to just drop something into vector[1000000000], the vector first has to allocate 0 through 999999999 to keep the internals consistent.

Comment: It may be worth to mention if trying to access non existing element using operator [] from std:map will insert that key with no value into map

Comment: @Steephen Yeah. That was a nasty surprise first time I found it. I naively expected to get NULL or something back that I could trigger on as "no such element"

Comment: @Steephen Yes, that is what I said. Not with "no value", it will default-construct a value.

Comment: @user4581301 If you want that behavior, you should either use [`at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at), which will throw, or [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find). Either way, it shouldn't be a "surprise" - there is ample documentation for these member functions.

Comment: @user4581301 Also, no, the point is to make `vector` as fast as possible. That's why `operator[]` does zero checking.

Comment: @Barry the real surprise was why I expected a non-pointer value to somehow return NULL. I knew it was impossible, and still expected magic to somehow happen.

Answer (score 1):

The subscript operators behave differently for `std::map` and for `std::vector`.

Subscript `[]` for map returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key that is equivalent to key. And if no such key exist, it will perform an **insertion** and return a reference to it.

Subscript `[]` for vector returns a reference to the element at the specified location. 
No bounds checking is performed. Vector `[]` operator *never* inserts a new element into the container.

Comment: Does your explanation apply to other containers? I mean, does [ ] work the same way for map/set/unordered_map etc? Does [ ] work the same way for vector / list / array / deque?

Comment: @Sarah vector, array and deque define the `[]` operator and work the same way returning a reference to requested element. Some containers don't define the subscript operator such as `std::set` and `std::list`, but you can use other methods such as `find()` for sets.